# Process.Start any way to delay the closing of the window?

Tags: c#, process

```
    public void ProcessStartAsAdmin(string command)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\application.EXE";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Verb = @"runas";
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = command;
        myProcess.Start();
    }
```

The Dos box closes very quickly and I can't tell if there are any errors or if it completed successfully. Is there anyway to keep the window alive until I manually close it?

Comment: Do you need to wait for the process to end or do you not care?

Comment: You could use a .cmd file instead that you write to the Temp directory.  Just two lines, second one can be PAUSE.  Or CHOICE if you want a timeout.

Comment: if "application.exe" is an application of yours, why not just put a sleep in it?

Comment: application.exe is not by me but it's by some other team. They wont change their code.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than running the application, start up a new shell (cmd.exe) and have that shell run the application by passing the command to run this application to it.  You can then exit the shell whenever you want using its "exit" command.

The other comparable solution is to create a batch script that just executes this command and then pauses for user input asking it to close.  Your program would then execute that script, instead of the application directly.

The other option is just to redirect the standard output to your application, instead of having it printed to the console, allowing you to do whatever you want with the output well after the program finishes execution.

Comment: The bat script wont work because I need to be able to take a password from my winform and pass it to the command prompt. How do i create my own shell? Will I be able to run commands within it as an Admin?

Comment: @softwareisfun You can write scripts that take input if you want.  As I said in the answer, the executable for the windows shell is cmd.exe, just start up an instance of *that* and you're now running your own shell.  You can then pass input to it through standard input.

Comment: Can you show me a sample of what you mean by "pass input through standard input"?

Comment: @softwareisfun You can look at the documentation for `Process` to see how to redirect standard input.  It has lots of examples.

Comment: Well I changed the application to C:\Windows\System32\CMD.EXE so I can launch my own Shell. As soon as it opens, it closes immediately afterwards.  I also added a line myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;